# Pointwise convergence of $\sin(xn)$ for $x\in [0;\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what values of $x$ does the sequence $f_n=\sin(xn),x\in [0,\pi]$ converge pointwise?

My thoughts are $x=0$ and $x=\pi$, but I am having troubles proving that for no other values it converges. Con someone give any hints, please?

Comment: I think the way I would go about it would be use the density of the numbers $\frac{p}{q}\pi\in[0,\pi]$ for $p\leq q$ and $p,q\in{\bf N}$, and then see if you can show that you can always find an $n>N$ which causes $\sin(\frac{p}{q}\pi n)$ to oscillate between two numbers, except for the boundary points of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. If $x=\frac ab\pi$ for a rational number, $a,b\in\Bbb N$ coprimes, then $\sin(nx)$ is *periodic* and has at least $b$ values, continuously repeated.
2. If $x=s\cdot2\pi$ for an irrational number $s$, then the sequence $\left( n\cdot s \pmod 1\right)_n $ (i.e. $(ns-\lfloor ns\rfloor)_n$) is *dense* in $[0,1]$, thus $\left(\sin(ns\cdot 2\pi)\right)_n$ is also dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, i think I managed to figure out the first hint. However, I am struggling with the second one. Why are we looking at $\sin(ns2\pi)$ not $\sin(ns2\pi)$? I also do not see how density helps here.

Comment: Dense means that *every* point (in $[-1,1]$) is a limit point, i.e. there is a subsequence that converges exactly there. So, that sequence will not converge to a single limit point.

Comment: oh, right, thank you.